# ORA-00984 column not allowed here

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, oracle-pro-c, ora-00984

I am getting error 
"Execute-984 ORA-00984: column not allowed here"
while I am inserting values in my table Registred_Customer using Pro*C

Registred_Customer is defined as

```
CREATE TABLE Registred_Customer (
    Cust_id NUMBER(6) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    Age NUMBER,
    Sex CHAR,
    Addr VARCHAR2(50),
    Contact NUMBER(10)
);
```

Inserting values using a pro*c method

```
addCustomer(i, name,age, gender, address,contectNo);
```

in Pro*C method I use following code to insert

```
EXEC SQL INSERT INTO REGISTRED_CUSTOMER VALUES  
(cust_id, cust_name, age, sex, addr,   contact);
```

here cust_name and addr are char *; and sex is char rest as int;

It reports error while using variable but works fine using direct values
like `EXEC SQL INSERT INTO REGISTRED_CUSTOMER VALUES (10, 'Pankaj', 23, 'M', 'asdfs', 45875);`

I tried changing few lines but in vain.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Your Pro*C code is basically missing the colons (assuming that your formal parameters are called `cust_id`, `cust_name`, `age` etc.):

```
EXEC SQL INSERT INTO REGISTRED_CUSTOMER VALUES  
    (:cust_id, :cust_name, :age, :sex, :addr, :contact);
```

And it would be more robust to explicitly specify the columns name. Otherwise a change to the table schema can result in difficult to find bugs:

```
EXEC SQL INSERT INTO REGISTRED_CUSTOMER (Cust_Id, Name, Ag, Sex, Addr, Contact)
    VALUES (:cust_id, :cust_name, :age, :sex, :addr, :contact);
```

Comment: +1, particularly for the advice to explicitly list column names.

Comment: I already tried working both solutions. With colons is says undefined identifier and with second part also error was not solved.

Answer (score 1):

If im seeing correct you are trying to insert into the columns, the columns??

"EXEC SQL INSERT INTO REGISTRED_CUSTOMER VALUES (cust_id, cust_name, age, sex, addr, contact);"??

it would be more helpful if you post your procedure complete.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

As Mr. mentioned, you are trying to use the columns as input values. When you provide actual values it works. Are you perhaps meaning to use PL/SQL variables or the procedure arguments? In this case, whatever your procedure parameters are called is what you should put in the values section.

i.e if addCustomer looks like

```
PROCEDURE addCustomer (pId NUMBER, pName VARCHAR2, pAge NUMBER, pGender CHAR, pAddress VARCHAR2, pContact NUMBER)
```

Then you'd do something like

```
INSERT INTO registered_customer (cust_id, name, age, sex, addr, contact) VALUES (pId, pName, pAge, pGender, pAddress, pContact);
```

But if you are inserting into all columns you can leave out the column definition and just provide values

Comment: Could it be that you haven't realized that the INSERT statement is run in a Pro*C context?

Comment: @ Chris Cameron-Mills
addcustomer is not a procedure. It is pro*c method which is being called by another cpp program. So this wont help.

Comment: Ah my mistake, yes I hadn't acknowledged Pro*C, the problem/explanation is still the same though, you are using column names in the VALUES section

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error message in a stored procedure doing an insert.  I misspelled a parameter name in the values clause and the oracle interpreter saw the misspelled name as a column name and issued the 00984.